# problem with Google cloud dataproc clusters create --properties tag

Tags: configuration, hadoop-yarn, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I was trying to enable yarn.log-aggregation-enable upon creating a Dataproc cluster using gcloud command like below, according to https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties

```sh
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create test1 
--properties= 'yarn:yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true' \
--max-idle=30m \
--no-address \
--network default \
--region=us-east4 \
--zone=us-east4-c \
--master-boot-disk-size=200GB \
--worker-boot-disk-size=100GB \
--num-workers=10 \
--worker-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
--master-machine-type=n1-standard-8
```

but I was informed:

> unrecognized arguments: yarn:yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true

How to put it right?
Is there another way to enable yarn.log-aggregation-enable on a Dataproc cluster?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a parsing error, you have both an equal sign (`=`) and a space () before the property: `--properties= 'yarn:yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true'`. Get rid of one and the command will accept the parameter: `--properties='yarn:yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true'`